# Pyspark: Convert String Datetime in 12 hour Clock to Date time with 24 hour clock (Time Zone Change)

Tags: datetime, pyspark, timestamp, clock

**Edit: Apologies, the sample data frame is a little off.  Below is the corrected sample dataframe I'm trying to convert:**

```
Timestamp (CST)
12/8/2018 05:23 PM
11/29/2018 10:20 PM
```

I tried the following code based on recommendation below but got null values returned.

```
df = df.withColumn('Timestamp (CST)_2', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col(('Timestamp (CST)')), "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss aa"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"))

df = df.withColumn("Timestamp (CST)_3", F.to_timestamp(F.col("Timestamp (CST)_2")))
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

I have a field called "Timestamp (CST)" that is a **string**.  It is in Central Standard Time.

```
Timestamp (CST)
2018-11-21T5:28:56 PM
2018-11-21T5:29:16 PM
```

How do I create a new column that takes "Timestamp (CST)" and change it to UTC and convert it to a datetime with the time stamp on the 24 hour clock?

Below is my desired table and I would like the datatype to be timestamp:

```
Timestamp (CST)_2
2018-11-21T17:28:56.000Z
2018-11-21T17:29:16.000Z
```

I tried the following code but all the results came back null:

```
df = df.withColumn("Timestamp (CST)_2", to_timestamp("Timestamp (CST)", "yyyy/MM/dd h:mm p"))
```

Comment: Do you want the desired one to be in timestamp or string format?

Comment: I would like the column to be a timestamp

Comment: You are using `yyyy/MM/dd` in to_timestamp but what you want is yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: You can achieve that in string not timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, import `from_unixtime`, `unix_timestamp` and `col` using

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_unixtime, unix_timestamp, col
```

Then, reconstructing your scenario in a `DataFrame` `df_time`

```
>>> cols = ['Timestamp (CST)']
>>> vals = [
...         ('2018-11-21T5:28:56 PM',),
...         ('2018-11-21T5:29:16 PM',)]
>>> df_time = spark.createDataFrame(vals, cols)
>>> df_time.show(2, False)
+---------------------+
|Timestamp (CST)      |
+---------------------+
|2018-11-21T5:28:56 PM|
|2018-11-21T5:29:16 PM|
+---------------------+
```

Then, my approach would be

```
>>> df_time_twenfour = df_time.withColumn('Timestamp (CST)', \
...             from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col(('Timestamp (CST)')), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss aa"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"))
>>> df_time_twenfour.show(2, False)
+------------------------+
|Timestamp (CST)         |
+------------------------+
|2018-11-21T17:28:56.000Z|
|2018-11-21T17:29:16.000Z|
+------------------------+
```

Notes

- If you want time to be in 24-Hour format then, you would use `HH` instead of `hh`.
- Since, you have a `PM`, you use `aa` in `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss aa` to specify PM.
- Your, input string has `T` in it so, you have to specify it as above format.

Comment: apologies for not including it in my sample but I have AM as well as PM.  How do I account for both in the code?

Comment: the option  `aa`  might give legacy errors. To fix it, replace 'aa' with `a`. The full code as below:
`df_time_twenfour = df_time.withColumn('Timestamp (CST)', \
...             from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col(('Timestamp (CST)')), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss a"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"))`

Answer (score 1):

the option `aa` as mentioned in @pyy4917's answer might give legacy errors. To fix it, replace `aa` with `a`.

The full code as below:

```
df_time_twenfour = df_time.withColumn('Timestamp (CST)', \ ...    
 from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col(('Timestamp (CST)')), \...
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss a"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"))
```