# Convert string time value in 12-hour format to time in 24-hour format

Tags: datetime, pyspark

The time value is present in the data as a string datatype with a 12-hour format. Need to convert this into time in 24-hour format.
Eg: 0123P -> 13:23:00

I tried using date_format, also tried [Pyspark: Convert String Datetime in 12 hour Clock to Date time with 24 hour clock (Time Zone Change)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731975/pyspark-convert-string-datetime-in-12-hour-clock-to-date-time-with-24-hour-cloc)
But its converting to null instead of correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll have to convert the string to a datetime and then format it to retain the timepart only.

here's an example

```py
spark.createDataFrame([('0123P',), ('0123A',)], ['timecol']). \
    withColumn('datetime', func.to_timestamp(func.concat('timecol', func.lit('M')), 'hhmma')). \
    withColumn('timeonly', func.date_format('datetime', 'HH:mm:ss')). \
    show()

# +-------+-------------------+--------+
# |timecol|           datetime|timeonly|
# +-------+-------------------+--------+
# |  0123P|1970-01-01 13:23:00|13:23:00|
# |  0123A|1970-01-01 01:23:00|01:23:00|
# +-------+-------------------+--------+
```